# tabBarController + changing orientation problem

Tags: iphone

I have a TabBarController with 4 views, and one of them is a scrollView. If i load this view, and then change the orientation of my device from portrait to landscape, the scrollview responds to the touches only 'till the pixel 320.

If later i go to another view, and then come back to the first, the scroll view works well even in landscape.

How can i adjust this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scroll view is probably not set to automatically adjust its height and width. If your view is built with Interface Builder, use the Autosizing section of the Size Inspector to set the struts & springs. Otherwise, if you're building your view programmatically, you'll need to set the `autoresizingMask` property to something appropriate.

Comment: I'm resizing the frame manually after the orientation changes. I tried with the autoresizing, but it does't change anything.
The scrollView resizes properly, the problem is only about the touch control!

Comment: Are you resizing the `frame` or the `bounds`?

Comment: Ok, removing the manual resize and let the autoresizing mask do the job works fine! Thanks!